# #Mark: equivalent in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to categorised method in dart file like in Xcode/Swift we use **//MARK**: Some Custom String for Quick view .

Also is there any setting in Android Stduio where i can see all method defined in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the IDE you're using.
On Android Studio / IntelliJ you can use the [region comments as explained here](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/06/21/android-studio-intellij-idea-code-regions/#.YGitihMza3I)

Comment: yes i am using Android studio. And it solved my problem. Also, But is there any settings in Android Studio where i can see all methods names defined in file. Editing OP

Comment: the link provided is broken

Comment: @lordvidex it works fine for me, but the website is pretty slow